# Message: A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

App won't run outside of VS 2019's Release folder, throwing this error in the event viewer: 
`Message: A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.`

.exe runs fine if put inside the Release folder, but I need it to run outside of it too, also ran it as debug multiple times inside the IDE and no problems whatsoever.

Anyone knows why does this happen?

[image: Screenshot of the error code]

UPDATE: Apparently moving the runtimeconfig.json outside of the folder gets me the same error... still i need the executable to run anywhere, not only in my Release folder or where there is my app's runtimeconfig.json file.

Comment: Sorry for the 3 dots in the screenshot, I just noticed them now.

Comment: I think runtimeconfig.json is from .net core, right?  If so, adding the .net-core tag would get the right eyes looking at it.

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3569) talks about it quite a bit.  You might be able to find an answer on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!
All I had to do is to right-click on the C# solution and hit "Publish".